# libgd vs rubygem local-fastimage_resize on M1

Tags: apple-silicon, ruby

This works on x86 mac but fails an M1 mac.

```
$ brew install pkg-config libgd
$ gem install local-fastimage_resize
```

I suspect it might be something with libgd packaging on M1. But could be something else as well.

I don't have an M1 mac so I can't debug it. I was hoping that somebody with M1 and necessary knowledge can help with this?

Some log Follows. (gem_make.out)

```
current directory: /Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/local-fastimage_resize-3.4.0/ext/fastimage_native_resize
/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/bin/ruby -I /Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20220923-95236-1gspepr.rb extconf.rb --with-gdlib\=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_3
checking for -l/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_3... no
missing libgd
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-gdlib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/2.6.0/local-fastimage_resize-3.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

(mkmf.log)

```
have_library: checking for -l/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_3... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/include/ruby-2.6.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -I/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/lib -L. -L/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/lib  -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.2.6   "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"clang -o conftest -I/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/include/ruby-2.6.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -I/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/lib -L. -L/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.8/lib  -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.2.6 -l/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_3   "
ld: library not found for -l/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return 0;
13: }
14: 
15: int t(void) { ; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

`brew --prefix gd` will show you the directory where libgd headers etc were installed by Homebrew. Specify this as `opt-dir` when installing the gem:

```
gem install local-fastimage_resize -- --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix gd)
```

If using bundler, execute

```
bundle config build.local-fastimage_resize --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix gd)
```

so the option is used when Bundler attempts to install the gem.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. That's nice. I found some documentation about setting environment based on Brewfile instead of individually setting up gems. I haven't had opportunity to validate that yet. +1 for information either case, as it is useful for custom library installations. Or multiple brew roots.